# AWS CloudWatch custom metrics best practice

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm running my Python web app on an EC2, and I want it to report some custom (app-level) metrics to CloudWatch.

Sample metrics are (uplink) request duration and similar.

From what I understand, I have to either use boto3 or the AWS CLI in order to do that. However:

1. My app doesn't use boto3 for functionality, so it seems like an overkill to use it just for reporting metrics
2. I have to be authenticated - unlike with Lambda, just the fact I'm running inside an EC2 does not mean I'm automatically authenticated.

What's the best practice here? My app doesn't **have** to run on EC2 (can be run it on GCP, Azure, or a custom server), so I really don't want to import boto3 into the code.

Answer (score 3):

You can look into [CloudWatch Embedded Metrics Format (EMF)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Embedded_Metric_Format_Specification.html).

You would need to [install and configure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Embedded_Metric_Format_Generation_CloudWatch_Agent.html) CloudWatch Agent on your EC2 instance and then you can use [python EMF library](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-embedded-metrics-python) to publish metrics.

With this approach:

- Your application is not calling CloudWatch APIs directly. CloudWatch agent does the publishing.
- You get custom metrics and EMF log entries in CloudWatch Logs, which can then be used with CloudWatch Logs Insights and Contributor Insights.

But you still need to provide a way to CloudWatch agent to authenticate against CloudWatch APIs. On EC2 instances this is done via the role your instance assumes.

Answer (score 2):

- You can attach role and have access to AWS cervices without credentials.
- It's all depends on your metric. Probably you don't need to use CloudWatch Metrics, but X-Ray in some cases.
- If your app doesn't use both3 it's not means what you need to use that, but it's easiest way to call AWS API
- If you are using GCP or Azure, please, use their monitoring services.
- If you need to collect some custom metrics from anywhere, please, use some metrics service or implement your own API

Comment: Please elaborate on "You can attach role and have access to AWS cervices without credentials".

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html